# Convert INT to TIME when leading zeros have been omitted

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column in the database stored as INT and I need to convert the column to TIME but all leading zeros have been omitted. Is there a way which this can be done?

Example:

```
HH:mm(UI)                 HHmmssSSS(db)
11:08                     1108ssSSS
04:36                     **0**436ssSSS
00:12                     **00**12ssSSS
00:05                     **000**5ssSSS
```

Comment: please give more clear data

Comment: What you tried to convert...?

Comment: `I have a column in the database stored as INT ` => Can you give sample? `I need to convert the column to TIME ` => What is expected output and what are u getting now?

Comment: Are you *guaranteed* that all of the stored values have 3 digits of decimals for the second portion (If not, then obviously the data isn't going to be recoverable, but it's worth checking before expending effort here)

Comment: Currently its stored as INT in the database but all leading zeros are not included which is shown in the second column above. I need to convert the column to TIME.

Answer (score 0):

To get those times:

```
with CTE as
(
select otherfields, right('0000' + cast(IntField as varchar),4) as StrTime
from MyTable
)
select otherfields, CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(StrTime,3,0,':'),6,0,':'),9,0,'.') AS TIME)
from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add minutes to get what you want.  The calculation requires some arithmetic:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               (intcol / 100) * 60 + (intcol % 100),
               cast(0 as time)
              )
```